# Springboot liquibase rollback lock on failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase, spring-boot-actuator

I have a basic SpringBoot application with basic liquibase configuration.

I need to rollback the lock created in table databasechangeloglock automatically created by liquibase.

In order to do this, I would like to find if there is any kind of springboot liquibase utility to automatically do this.

Right now I am planning on exposing `/shutdown` endpoint in actuator, and call directly to databse via common JPA repository, something like:

```java
@RestController
public class ShutdownController implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired
    private MyRepo myRepo;

    @PostMapping("/shutdownContext")
    public void shutdownContext() {
        myRepo.setDatabaseChangeLogLock(false);
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        this.context = ctx;

    }
}
```

Isn't there a better way to do this? Just using Springboot liquibase?